# Commits from different branch on GitHub Pull Request

Tags: git, svn, github, pull-request

I'm working with a fork of our company's app on GitHub. We have a develop branch and we are creating new branches from develop to work on like (*like `feature/new-feature`*) and creating pull request to original repo when our work finished. Of course doing a rebase before creating PR.

After rebase some commits (**commitA** and **commitC**) from different developer merged to my branch. And now in my PR these commits also listing as file changes. And have conflict with develop.

In shortly,
My PR's commit list is like this:

`commitA <---this commmit is different developers and shouldn't be listed here
commitB
commitC <---this commmit is different developers and shouldn't be listed here
...`

How can I remove these commits from my PR? These commits (commitA and commitC) is also on develop branch.

My branch should have only commit B, commitA and commitC belongs to develop branch, not my branch.

Comment: Look into doing an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i`), assuming you really want to remove commits `A` and `C` from your history.  You could also update your question to show us how you want the branch to look after doing your desired modification.

Comment: I don't want to remove them completely, these commits belongs to develop it should stay there. They should be listing on PR like new commits. Because they are causing to conflict while merging my PR with develop. But yes I want to remove them from **my branch**.

Comment: My understanding of what you want is correct then.  Just do an interactive rebase and remove these commits then.  Keep in mind you will have to force push the branch to the repository, since you will have rewritten history.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen which command should I use for commits? **pick** for my commits and which one for unwanted commits?

Comment: For the unwanted commits, just delete the lines (yes, it's that simple).  Complete the rebase and you should be good to go.  You might want to create a test branch first to make sure you have the hang of it.  If the result is what you want, go back and do it on the real branch.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please send this as answer so I can accept it? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a Git rebase in interactive mode, and then selectively remove the `A` and `C` commits which you don't want.  Assuming you want to see the last 5 commits during the rebase, you can do the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

This will open an editor containing a file looking something like the following:

```
pick dl4mn23 commitA comment
pick 47kmeu6 commitB comment
pick k39fn39 commitC comment
pick lsw42fg commitD comment
pick mk837dc commitE comment
```

To remove the `A` and `C` commits, you can simply delete the corresponding lines, leaving you with this:

```
pick 47kmeu6 commitB comment
pick lsw42fg commitD comment
pick mk837dc commitE comment
```

Save the file and exit the editor, which should begin the rebase.  You may have to resolve merge conflicts.  Once you have completed the rebase, you can verify that you have the history you want using `git log`.

As one other note, since you rewrote the history of this branch, you will have to force push it to the remote via:

```
git push origin feature --force
```

Comment: @Eray Here is your answer, glad to be of service.